# Create several copies of file with one line in each copy changed

Tags: bash, scripting, python

I have to automate simulations and to do so I need to create input files for each simulation. The majority of my simulations are almost identical, with one line of text changed from one file to the next.
How can I take a text file, and make a number of copies of it with a specific line changed? For example if a text file held:

```
! input file
a = 6
b = 6
d = 789
! end
```

Say I wanted to create 6 new files from this template but my variable b is reduced by one in each subsequent file, how can I do this in either bash or python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basic method can be similar to this in example i modify a= value bye numbers & files  & filename also have value inside so it is separated files

```
#!/bin/bash


for i in a b c 1 2 3  ; do
    cat > file${i} << EOT
! input file
a = ${i}
b = 6
d = 789
! end
EOT
done
```

so you get 6 files with 6 different contents as :

```
# cat file?
! input file
a = 1
b = 6
d = 789
! end
! input file
a = 2
b = 6
d = 789
! end
! input file
a = 3
b = 6
d = 789
! end
! input file
a = a
b = 6
d = 789
! end
! input file
a = b
b = 6
d = 789
! end
! input file
a = c
b = 6
d = 789
! end
```

if you have to read b value from a reference file 
you can user a variable from read subcommand for example

```
while read ; do
cat > file${REPLY} << EOT
! input file
a = 1
b = ${REPLY}
d = 789
! end
EOT
done < referencefile
```

full example in real condition :

```
[root@h2g2w tmp]# cat > ./test.sh
while read ; do
cat > file${REPLY} << EOT
! input file
a = 1
b = ${REPLY}
d = 789
! end
EOT
done < referencefile


[root@h2g2w tmp]# cat > referencefile 
qsd
gfd
eza
vxcv
bxc
[root@h2g2w tmp]# 
[root@h2g2w tmp]# sh ./test.sh 
[root@h2g2w tmp]# ls -lrth file???
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 41 28 juin  22:47 fileqsd
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 41 28 juin  22:47 filegfd
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 41 28 juin  22:47 fileeza
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 41 28 juin  22:47 filebxc
[root@h2g2w tmp]# cat file???
! input file
a = 1
b = bxc
d = 789
! end
! input file
a = 1
b = eza
d = 789
! end
! input file
a = 1
b = gfd
d = 789
! end
! input file
a = 1
b = qsd
d = 789
! end
[root@h2g2w tmp]#
```

I hope you can now adapt that to your needs.

Comment: I have read both this answer and glenn's, and I want to select the one that works best for my needs, so I will be attempting to implement these before I do so. Thank you very much. I especially like that I can write one bash script that contains the template to be copied. Thank you

Comment: Quick question , if there is a second variable that needs to be changed also, from a different range of values, how can I incorporate that into your answer? Say that when a changes, so does b, but string values?

Answer (score 0):

With just bash: the file is named "file"

```
# slurp the whole file into a variable
contents=$(< file)

# find the value of b, using regular expression
# - with bash regex, the literal parts are quoted and the metachars are not
if [[ $contents =~ "b = "([0-9]+) ]]; then
    b_val=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

    # create a printf-style format string
    template=${contents/b = $b_val/b = %d}

    # then, count down from the b value to 1, creating the new files
    for (( n = b_val; n >= 1; n-- )); do
        printf "$template\n" $n > "file.$n"
    done
fi
```

Then:

```
$ ls -lt
total 6220
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jackman jackman      39 Jun 28 17:46 file.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jackman jackman      39 Jun 28 17:46 file.2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jackman jackman      39 Jun 28 17:46 file.3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jackman jackman      39 Jun 28 17:46 file.4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jackman jackman      39 Jun 28 17:46 file.5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jackman jackman      39 Jun 28 17:46 file.6
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jackman jackman      39 Jun 28 17:35 file
...

$ grep ^b file{,.?}
file:b = 6
file.1:b = 1
file.2:b = 2
file.3:b = 3
file.4:b = 4
file.5:b = 5
file.6:b = 6
```